# Using luac file on Nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I have been experimenting with using Lua in Nginx - quite a neat little capability which I can use effectively.  However, one of my concerns relates to IP protection so I thought I would use an online tool to compile my, fully tested, LUA script.  I tried https://luac.mtasa.com/.

I uploaded the file to my server, changed by `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file to use the *luac** instead of the orginal *lua* and reloaded nginx.  However, when I attempt to browse to the resource that is being serviced by that lua(c) I get the error log message `*70 failed to load external Lua file... : bad byte code header`.  How should this be interpreted?  The options are

- That particular online compiler is not generating a valid luac.
- The nginx/lua combo does not understand that particular luac.

I should mention that I am using Nginx 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit). I installed Lua enabled Nginix via `apt-get install nginx-extras`.

I am a beginner here.

Comment: Have you read this? http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#Lua.2FLuaJIT_bytecode_support

Comment: Perfect!  Write that up as an answer and I will upvote + accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling lua for nginx has some specifics. You could see details on official Lua module page http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#Lua.2FLuaJIT_bytecode_support